# Oracle SQL Constraints same value in other tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need a short answers how to make constraints when
I have table A, B, C, E

- Table E have E_ID (E id is primary key)
- Table B have B_ID, E_ID (E id are foreign keys)
- Table C have C_ID, E_ID (E id are foreign key)
- Table A have A_ID,B_ID,C_ID (B and C id are foreign keys)

where id are primary keys.

I want constrain to make sure I table A i have records where C_ID and B_ID has same E_ID.
And it should still have 3rd normal form.

Comment: Foreign keys anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following four constraints:

```
alter table a add constraint fk1 foreign key (b_id) references b (b_id);
alter table a add constraint fk2 foreign key (c_id) references c (c_id);
alter table c add constraint fk3 foreign key (e_id) references e (e_id);
alter table b add constraint fk4 foreign key (e_id) references e (e_id);
```

Comment: Insert (1,1) into B and (2,2) into C and (3,1,2) into A ... this is valid by your constraints but not valid by the additional constraint that the `E_ID` values need to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to repeat `e_id` in table `a` and then use this for foreign key constraints.

Note the foreign key relationships to the unique keys in this data model:

```
create table e (eid int primary key);

create table b (bid int primary key, 
                eid int references e(eid),
                unique (bid, eid)
               );

create table c (cid int primary key, 
                eid int references e(eid),
                unique (cid, eid)
               );

create table a (aid int primary key, 
                bid int references b(bid),
                cid int references c(cid),
                eid int references e(eid),
                foreign key (bid, eid) references b(bid, eid),
                foreign key (cid, eid) references c(cid, eid)
               );
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e941b1) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Will it be still 3rd normal form?

Comment: @Fenrir . . . I don't think so.  It might depend on whether `eid` is really an independent attribute for the three entities.  But if you wouldn't have such an attribute in `a`, then adding it would not be consistent with 3rd normal form.